# Passing value to .ashx from aspx jquery for uploadify

Tags: c#, uploadify

What I need to be done: I am trying to implement Uploadify to upload video files to the server. I am able to upload the files and save the value in database using the handler. But I need to pass a textbox value to the upload.ashx. Following is the code I am using to pass the value:

---

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>").uploadify({
            'uploader': '../scripts/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '../Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': '../images/cancel.png',
            'folder': 'UploadFiles',
            **'scriptData': { 'comment': $("#<%=tbVideoName.ClientID%>").val() },**
            'multi': true
        });

        $("#startUploadLink").click(function () {
            $('#<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>').uploadifyUpload();
            return false;
        });

        $("#clearQueueLink").click(function () {
            $("#<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>").uploadifyClearQueue();
            return false;
        });

    });
```

And bellow is how I am getting the value on the handler:

```
school.videoname = context.Request["comment"];
```

But the above code does not give me the value in the textbox on the handler.
Can anyone please check where am I doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to set the comment when you uploadify the div (or whatever) when the page is ready. You really want to be doing this in the #startUploadLink click handler.

I believe you can do something like this:

```
$('#<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>').uploadify('settings','scriptData',{
    'comment': $("#<%=tbVideoName.ClientID%>").val()
});
```

Comment: I have added changed following your answer to get no change in the function:


`$('#<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>').uploadifyUpload({
                    'scriptData': { 'comment': $("#<%=tbVideoName.ClientID%>").val() }
                });`